# NetMQ:I am new to .Net and NetMQ. I am working on a Pub:Sub pattern application in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, windows-firewall, netmq

Here is my code for publisher

```
 private void CreateMessages()
    {
        using (var QuotePublishSocket = new PublisherSocket("tcp://192.168.0.9:9011"))
        {
            QuotePublishSocket.Options.SendHighWatermark = 10009;
            QuotePublishSocket.Bind("tcp://*:9011");
            QuotePublishSocket.SendFrame("Hello :" + DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds());;

        }
    }
```

And this is my code for subscriber

```
private void CreateSubscriberTread(string portNo) {
        using (var subSocket = new SubscriberSocket())
        {
            subSocket.Options.ReceiveHighWatermark = 1000;
            subSocket.Connect("tcp://192.168.0.9:9011");
            //subSocket.Bind("tcp://*:9011");
            subSocket.Subscribe("");
            Console.WriteLine("Subscriber socket connecting...");
            while (true)
            {
                string messageReceived = subSocket.ReceiveFrameString();
                Console.WriteLine(messageReceived );

            }
        }

    }
```

But when I run publisher&subscriber on the same PC it works and I receive data from publisher. But when I run publisher&subscriber on two different pc I won't receive any data. please guide me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Google "windows configure firewall" to get ahead.

Comment: Thx @Hans Passant